# emacs workgroups2: Possible to have different buffers for each workgroup?

Tags: emacs

I'm not sure what the normal behaviour is here, but I would like to have multiple workgroups, each with its associated buffers. So, for example, I could have `my-python-workgroup` which has a bunch of python files open in the buffer, and a `my-ssh-workgroup` which has buffers associated with a server connection.

Right now it seems like once I launch emacs and switch between workgroups, my buffers end up accumulating. Is there any way to keep buffers separate?

Answer (score 0):

Spacemacs has this capability through what it calls 'Layouts'. Layouts gives you *buffer isolation*, so that you can keep your python and ssh buffers in separate groups, for instance. You can also save and load layouts. See here:

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-layouts

The disadvantage is that it does not save shells (ehsell, ansi-term, inferior python, etc.), so you can't load up a combination of python files and an inferior python buffer on restart. Workgroups2 has this capability, but it does not allow buffer isolation. It would be great if these two concepts could be combined!